# By how much is a wand's price raised if unicorn horn is added during its creation?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

My character is making a *wand of lesser vigor* (*Spell Compendium* 229). The spell has the same level as *cure light wounds* so I'd expect such a wand to sell for 750 gp eventually. However, I am using a unicorn horn during creation ("If a horn taken from a unicorn that has died of natural causes is used as a component in the casting of any touch spell that has the healing descriptor, it transforms the spell into a ray with a 30 foot range" (*Complete Champion* 133)). The unicorn horn costs 190 gp, so will my new *wand of ray of lesser vigor* sell for 940 gp? (Assuming this kind of item creation is legal.)

Comment: I'm guessing the horn is a single-use item? I doubt you'd be able to multiply it's power by 50 that easily.

Comment: it's a single use item yes, but the spell used during creation is also used only once. I don't think creating a wand of teleport, for example, would require me to cast 50 teleport spells...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* on [Creating Wands](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-wands) says, "Fifty of each needed material component are required, one for each charge" (288), so while the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell *lesser vigor* [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 229) doesn't normally need any material components, power components "can be used even with spells that do not normally have material components[, and like] other material components, they disappear when used to cast a spell" (*Complete Champion* 131).

Thus this DM, were he to allow a wand's creator to incorporate power components into a magic item would treat them as normal expensive material components, making a *wand of lesser vigor (1st-level spell at caster level 1) modified by the power component unicorn horn* cost 750 gp *plus* 9,500 gp (190 gp per unicorn horn power component × 50 charges), or 10,250 gp.

Note that "[e]ach of the power components… must be specially prepared by methods not normally available to player characters" (*CC* 131), so a source beyond the PCs must be found to acquire the power components. It's not as though the PCs can reap a multitude of unicorn horn power components by, like, starting a unicorn hospice.